# What is a better way to write multiple try clauses for casting a json string object to a dataclass?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, try-except, python-dataclasses

I have a function that receives multiple different json string objects with different structure and/or field names, like so:

```
event = '{"userId": "TDQIQb2fQaORKvCyepDYoZgsoEE3", "profileIsCreated": true}'
```

or

```
event = '{"userId": "TDQIQb2fQaORKvCyepDYoZgsoEE3", "signUpFinished": true}'
```

And I have data classes like so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass_json(letter_case=LetterCase.CAMEL)
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class UserId:
    userId: str


@dataclass_json(letter_case=LetterCase.CAMEL)
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SignUpFinished(UserId):
    signUpFinished: bool


@dataclass_json(letter_case=LetterCase.CAMEL)
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class UserProfileCreated(UserId):
    profileIsCreated: bool
```

Currently, the way I write my function is like this:

```
def cast_event(event):
    user_details = None

    try:
        user_details = SignUpFinished.from_json(event)
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        user_details = UserProfileCreated.from_json(event)
    except KeyError:
        pass

    if user_details:
        return "OK"
    else:
        return "UNHANDLED"
```

The problem is, as I have more and more events to handle, my function will become longer and longer, however, it is only doing the same thing.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want to achieve?

---

I have checked out some of the SO questions:

- [Multiple try codes in one block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block)
- [Python: Multiple try except blocks in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851243/python-multiple-try-except-blocks-in-one)

but they don't seem to be the best way of trying to achieve what I want.

Comment: I'd advise to try to have a more formal differentiation here, like `{"event": "signupFinished", "data": {...}}`, which then easily allows you to switch on the `event` key to determine what data structure you're dealing with. Brute-forcing it seems like a bad approach, and will get messy if two different dataclasses may be able to deserialise the same JSON.

Comment: can i confirm what you meant by that? so when sending the `event` to the function `cast_event`, I should add the event type as a field in the payload like you showed? and the actual event will be in `data`? so, i'd imagine i'd have like a lookup `dict` or something to use the proper dataclass?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Set it up so you can map one value to a specific dataclass, instead of basically needing to look at the entire message as a whole to decide what dataclass it is.

Comment: Are you able to post an answer with some working code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each case is syntactically the same, you can handle them in a single loop. Iterate through a sequence of cases and `try` to `return`; this automatically keeps on trying later cases until one succeeds.

```
def cast_event(event):
    for case in (UserId , SignUpFinished, UserProfileCreated):
        try:
            return case.from_json(event)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    raise ValueError(f'not a valid event: {event}')
```

Answer (score 2):

While a [loop approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59766060) works to solve your question as asked, it would be a lot better if you didn't need a "brute force" approach to deserialising your data in the first place. To do that, you'd need a field which unambiguously helped you determine what kind of data structure you're dealing with. E.g.:

```
event = {'event': 'profile',
         'data': {'userId': 'TDQIQb2fQaORKvCyepDYoZgsoEE3', 'profileIsCreated': True}}
```

Here the event `'profile'` will always be followed by an object with the keys `'userId'` and `'profileIsCreated'`. That is the guarantee your event messages should make, then it's trivial to parse them:

```
event_map = {
    'profile': UserProfileCreated,
    ...
}

return event_map[event['event']](**event['data'])
```

Note that I'm skipping the JSON-parsing step here. You'll need to parse the JSON first to evaluate its `event` key, so using `dataclass_json` is probably superfluous/not useful then.

Comment: can you add the part where you parse the json to `dataclass`? i am not sure if i understand your suggestion completely or not.

Comment: That last line is where the parsed JSON data gets passed to the dataclass constructor. The actual JSON parsing is omitted here, but is a simple call to `json.load` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For the specified source data, you can do this:

```py
import json

data = '{"userId": "TDQIQb2fQaORKvCyepDYoZgsoEE3", "profileIsCreated": true}'

data = json.loads(data)

user_id = data.pop('userId')
user_details_key = list(data.keys())[0] if data else None
user_details = list(data.values())[0] if data else None

assert user_id == 'TDQIQb2fQaORKvCyepDYoZgsoEE3'
assert user_details_key == 'profileIsCreated'
assert user_details == True
```