# More elegant way to write multiple try, except

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a better way to write a multiple condition try-except statement,

Actually I check for some condition "A" and if it fails, well I look for "B",

In this case I am trying 2 different scenarios for selenium webdriver. Sometimes I try more than 2 options

```
    try:
        message_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button/div[contains(text(), "Anybody")]')))
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            message_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span/div[contains(text(), "Somebody")]')))
            return False
        except Exception as e:
            return "yes"
```

Also a way to look for both a at a time would be nice!

Comment: See if the OR'ed XPATH works for you: `//button/div[contains(text(), "Anybody")] | //span/div[contains(text(), "Somebody")]`.

Comment: You could create a function that accepts either the entire function, or just the xpath string, with one try/except block and returns the value. Then you can put all of your xpath strings in a list, and do a lambda to run the list through the function. The basic concept can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874666/how-to-write-multiple-try-statements-in-one-block-in-python

Comment: In this case you mention, will it wait 20 secs for any of the options, right? In case there is a match with both, what will happen? @JustinEzequiel

Comment: You'll just have to try it yourself.

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to do this. If it's for testing this isn't a great approach, if it's for something else (scraping) you might want ot use a different technique: like the xpath OR...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of different things you do.
you could OR in the xpath as noted above:

```
 message_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button/div[contains(text(), "Anybody")] | //span/div[contains(text(), "Somebody")]')))
```

python does have [any_of](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#any_of) (available in selenium4) that behaves like a logical or:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.any_of(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button/div[contains(text(), "Anybody")]')),
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span/div[contains(text(), "Somebody")]')))
    )
)
```

Comment: you should notice that feature any_of available in selenium4 >= and install:
`pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7`

Comment: I did note that but I'll edit to specify the version.